# I want use the values in my dict., too calculate - but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
mydict = {"test1": (2,3), "test2": (1)}

for key,value in mydict.items():
    mydict[key] = 1/(1+value)
print(mydict)
```

But I get this error:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'"
```

The thing that I want is this:

For test1 that contains of two values, I want the following:

```
1/(a+1) + 1/(b+1) = 0.5833
```

a and b being the values in the tuple for the corresponding key

```
test1 = 0.5833
```

similarly, for test2

```
1/(a+1) = 1/2 = 0.5

test2 = 0.5
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen when `value` is `(2, 3)`?

Comment: for `"test1"` you are trying to do `1/(1+(2, 3))` which of course fails.. You cannot add `1` to `(2, 3)`

Comment: Your `value` is of type `tuple`, so you are trying to add a tuple and and integer. That's not possible.

Comment: Your value is a tuple.. so your calculation is actually 1/ ( 1+(2,3) ) which is not well defined.

Comment: Assuming this worked, how do you get `0,5833` (or `0.5833`) from `(1/(1+2.3))`?

Comment: Which I try to say, I want for test1: 1 /(2+1) + 1/(3+1) = 0,5833

Comment: It seems that you are using commas instead of points. In Python (2,3) is a tuple, not a floating point number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to iterate through the the tuple. I have amended your code below and added comments of points of interest. Please let me know if this works as expected?

```
mydict = {"test1": (2,3 ), "test2": ( 1)}

for key,value  in mydict.items():
    # state the value as 0 to allow iterations to be added to together
    mydict[key] = 0

    # we check if it is a integer
    if not isinstance(value, int): 
        #if not an integer we interate through the values
        for x in value:
            # add the value to the total
            mydict[key] += 1/(1+x)

    else:
        mydict[key] = 1/(1+value)
print(mydict)
```

Comment: `1/3.3` would be `0.30..` though, not `0.58..`

Comment: No, 
I didn't intend to have a comma.

For test1 that contains of two values, I want the following: 
1/(2+1) + 1/(3+1) = 0,5833 -> For that key.